# class-wp-hook.php on line 288

Tags: wp-admin, errors, warnings

Can someone help me with this error my website is not working even wp-admin page I'm getting this error message I have tried to disable all plugins but still same error?

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'wp_pre_kses_block_attributes' not found or invalid
>   function name in /home//public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on
>   line 288
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'wp_pre_kses_block_attributes' not found or invalid
>   function name in /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on
>   line 288
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'wp_pre_kses_block_attributes' not found or invalid
>   function name in /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on
>   line 288
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'wp_pre_kses_block_attributes' not found or invalid
>   function name in /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on
>   line 288
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'wp_pre_kses_block_attributes' not found or invalid
>   function name in /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on
>   line 288
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'wp_pre_kses_block_attributes' not found or invalid
>   function name in /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on
>   line 288
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'wp_pre_kses_block_attributes' not found or invalid
>   function name in /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on
>   line 288
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/aryshe5/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:288) in
>   /home/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1265
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/aryshe5/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:288) in
>   /home/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1268

Comment: There is a hook that isn't finding the function/callable that was attached to it 'wp_pre_kses_block_attributes'. I cannot help much without knowing more. We need to know where the 'wp_pre_kses_block_attributes' function comes from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstalling core should fix this issue. This is more than likely related to a botched update from 5.3 to 5.3.1.

**Edit:** To clarify, 5.3.1 included some hardening with relation to kses (specifically `wp_kses_bad_protocol()`) as noted in the [release post](https://wordpress.org/news/2019/12/wordpress-5-3-1-security-and-maintenance-release/).

In the error output above, a core file was referencing a core function that didn't exist, which tells us that one core file was updated but another one elsewhere was not. So "botched update" is the conclusion.

As for *why* the update didn't work, your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just received the same error and went into wp-admin and chose to upgrade from WordPress 5.3 to 5.3.1, that resolved the errors.

Comment: Thank you chuckfinley the error has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling WordPress latest version from the dashboard options fixed this issue for me! :)

Just a corrupt update essentially.